# concatenate two one-dimensional to two columns array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
aa = np.array([1], [2], [3])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3])
bb = np.array([1], [2], [3])
np.concatenate((a, b), axis = 1)
array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])     # It's ok, that's what I was expecting
np.concatenate((a, b), axis = 0)
array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])     # It's not ok, that's not what I was expecting
```

I was expecting:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

even with aa and bb I get the same inconsistency.
so is there a simple solution to concatenate along axis 0 two one-dimensional arrays?

Comment: The first example is not OK, `axis=1` is undefined (and will eventually give an error).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that `a` and `b` are both one-dimensional; there's no axis 1 to concatenate along.  You want [`vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> b = a.copy()
>>> np.vstack([a,b])
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Alternatively, you could reshape `a` and `b` first:

```
>>> np.concatenate([a[np.newaxis,:],b[np.newaxis,:]],axis = 0)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```