# Why does numpy.concatenate work along axis=1 for small one dimensional arrays, but not larger ones?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

I couldn't get my 4 arrays of year, day of year, hour, and minute to concatenate the way I wanted, so I decided to test several variations on shorter arrays than my data.

I found that it worked using method "t" from my test code:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
b=np.array([[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]])
c=np.array([[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]])
d=np.array([[31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]])

print a
print b
print c
print d

q=np.concatenate((a, b, c, d), axis=0)
#concatenation along 1st axis
print q

t=np.concatenate((a.T, b.T, c.T, d.T), axis=1)
#transpose each array before concatenation along 2nd axis
print t

x=np.concatenate((a, b, c, d), axis=1)
#concatenation along 2nd axis
print x
```

But when I tried this with the larger arrays it behaved the same as method "q".

I found an alternative approach of using vstack [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482696/concatenate-two-one-dimensional-to-two-columns-array) that did what I wanted, but I am trying to figure out why concatenation sometimes works for this, but not always.

Thanks for any insights.

Also, here are the outputs of the code:

**q:**

```
[[ 1  2  3  4  5  6]    
 [11 12 13 14 15 16]    
 [21 22 23 24 25 26]
 [31 32 33 34 35 36]]
```

**t:**

```
[[ 1 11 21 31]
 [ 2 12 22 32]
 [ 3 13 23 33]
 [ 4 14 24 34]
 [ 5 15 25 35]
 [ 6 16 26 36]]
```

**x:**

```
[[ 1  2  3  4  5  6 11 12 13 14 15 16 21 22 23 24 25 26 31 32 33 34 35 36]]
```

**EDIT:** I added method t to the end of a section of the code that was already fixed with vstack, so you can compare how vstack will work with this data but not concatenate.  Again, to clarify, I found a workaround already, but I don't know why the concatenate method doesn't seem to be consistent.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np


BAO10m=np.genfromtxt('BAO_010_2015176.dat', delimiter=",", usecols=range(0-6), dtype=[('h', int), ('year', int), ('day', int), ('time', int), ('temp', float)])
#10 meter weather readings at BAO tower site for June 25, 2015

hourBAO=BAO10m['time']/100
minuteBAO=BAO10m['time']%100
#print hourBAO
#print minuteBAO
#time arrays

dayBAO=BAO10m['day']
yearBAO=BAO10m['year']
#date arrays

datetimeBAO=np.vstack((yearBAO, dayBAO, hourBAO, minuteBAO))
#t=np.concatenate((a.T, b.T, c.T, d.T), axis=1)  <this gave desired results in simple tests
#not working for this data, use vstack instead, with transposition after stack
print datetimeBAO
test=np.transpose(datetimeBAO)
#rotate array
print test
#this prints something that can be used for datetime

t=np.concatenate((yearBAO.T, dayBAO.T, hourBAO.T, minuteBAO.T), axis=1)
print t
#this prints a 1D array of all the year values, then all the day values, etc...
#but this method worked for shorter 1D arrays
```

The file I used can be found at [this site.](ftp://ftp1.esrl.noaa.gov/psd3/bao/Tower/Processed/daily/)

Comment: You have not clearly explained what is going wrong.

Comment: What's the shape of the larger arrays.  All `vstack` does is make sure the inputs are all 2d, i.e by passing them through `atleast_2d(_m)`.

Comment: hpaulj, the larger arrays are 1d, unless there is something I am completely missing.  I added more example code that includes the larger arrays as well, let me know if there is other clarification needed.